# hmtl:play video in fullscreen mode and pause when backpressed (exit fullscreen mode)

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, video

i am using below code to play video
see link for detail :http://liveweave.com/gaDcmn

```
    var v = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 

    $(document).on('click', v, function (e) {
        if (v.paused === false) {
            v.pause();
        } else {
            v.webkitEnterFullscreen();
            v.play();
        }

        return false;
    });

<video width="80%" height="auto" controls="controls" id="myVideo">
                <source src="video/kitkat_converted.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
```

now 
i am able to play pause vidoe in my brwoser but i get belwo problem in android browser:

```
 1. 1:i want that when we click play button it plays in fullscreen mode 
    but when i click again it does not gets paused

 2: Problem in both android When i backpress   fullscreen video in android  or browser exitfullscreen video

Video must get paused but it keeps on playing , what to do to pause video when not in fullscreen mode
```

what to do for it